# How to catch DB error in codeinigter

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, codeigniter-3

I want to catch database error like (Duplicate values or error number 1062 or 1451 ) in codeigniter then return it out. Please help me for this problem.
* Sorry for bad English *

```html
public function delete($id){
  $this->db->where('pro_img_id', $id);
  $this->db->delete('tb_image');
  if($this->db->_error_number() == 1602){
    return 'duplicate error';
  }else if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
    return 'success';
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($query);
```

You can also use (in view) and you will see the SQL statement:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

this is the mysql_error() wrapper.

```
$this->db->_error_message();
```

And the mysql_errno wrapper is:

```
$this->db->_error_number();
```